# Unavailable Shared Path using net use via xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xp-cmdshell, net-use

I have been trying to resolve this really weird issue for a while!

We have a stored procedure that performs the below (all executed via `xp_cmdshell` which is run using the proxy account that is set to the service account)

1. `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use /delete X:'`
2. `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use X: \\<server_ip>\FOLDER`
3. `exec xp_cmdshell 'X:\SomeExeFile.exe'`

However, when running step 3, I am getting a 'The system cannot find the drive specified'. Running `exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami'` between steps 2 and 3 gives me the service account user, but running `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use'` between steps 2 and 3 states that X: is 'Unavailable' !

Moreover, at this point, running '`net use`' from a cmd window (which is run as the service account user) also gives 'Unavailable' but when I execute all the above steps 1-3 again from the cmd window, everything works fine.

(And to further add, running `exec xp_cmdshell 'net use'` from SSMS after doing the above via cmd then gives 'Disconnected X:' )

I cannot seem to understand what is happening since I am under the impression that net use executed on cmd and net use executed via xp_cmdshell should be the same. Can anyone help me understand why running '`net use`' via xp_cmdshell just after creating it using same user is giving 'Unavailable' please?

Thanks in advance!

PS: what's weird is that when I run the above from SSMS connected with a sysadmin account, this issue is not present!

Comment: Well, does service account have access to the share?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. If not, it would not have worked via cmd window either no?

Comment: I don't know, it's a bit unclear from which accounts you run the cmd parts from. Does it help to put all your code into same .bat file and run everything at once?

Comment: Some stuff on windows doesn't always work when impersonating (which i guess proxy account is doing), vs actually running as specific user, maybe it could be that.

Comment: I'm running the cmd window using 'run as different user' and inputting the service account credentials. Infact, executing 'whoami' gives me the service account username. I will give the .bat file idea a go!

Comment: The .bat file idea actually works! Very strange that running same commands via xp_cmdshell individually does not :(

Comment: I suspect the share thing is "lost" after impersonation ends, which is done at the end of each xp_cmdshell call.

Comment: That could be very well true. Feel free to add this info as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Done! Glad to be of some help

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that after each xp_cmdshell call, the end of impersonation "kills" the share, and that's why it works to run it in one go.

As a workaround, you can put the whole script into .bat file and execute it